# Cannot Run Rscript from PHP but it runs perfect from terminal

Tags: command-line, permissions, apache2, sudo, php

I'm new to Ubuntu
I'm trying to execute an Rscript in PHP using exec. However it doesnt run.
When I run it from the terminal it executes perfectly.

This is the code I run from commandline:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript /home/xin/Documents/ClassificationApp/ClassificationAllInOne.R "http://localhost/categorisation/public/classification/data/1423242832.json"
```

It works perfectly.

From searching around i can deduce it is a permissions issue as PHP/apache runs as www-data and Rscript is root.

I've tried a number of ammendments to the `Sudoers` file none of which worked:-

```
User_Alias WWW_USER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias WWW_COMMANDS =  /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript, /home/xin/Documents/Classifi$

WWW_USER ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: WWW_COMMANDS
```

This hasn't worked. I've spent a day messing around with various combinations. It's driving me mad.

Any inspiration would be most welcome

M

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Do you have the PHP cli installed? ;-)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the information what happens under php-cli?

Comment: Hi thanks so I got it working, it was pretty easy in the end, I gave www-data sudo rights to Rscript and ClassificationAllInOne.R in the sudoers file.......the program launched:)

Comment: Glad that I was able to help.  Shall I convert that to an answer?

Comment: Sure thanks. It led to another problem I have a line of R code that throws an error when run from PHP but doesnt throw any error when run from the commandline. I'll have to post that as another question.

Comment: With R itself, I will not be able to help you, unfortunately...  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging PHP code that executes external scripts (`R`, `bash`, ...)  the easiest thing to do is to install `php-cli`

```
sudo apt-get install php-google-api-php-client
```

`php-cli` means "PHP Command Line Interface". As the name suggests, it's is a way of using PHP from the terminal.

then execute the script using `/usr/bin/php -q <?php YourPHPCodeHere; ?>`

Alternatively, create a file that contains the PHP code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
echo "Hello world...";
?>
```

then `chmod +x szNameOfFile`

and then just type `./szNameOfFile`

If you don't want to type the full path to your PHP script, just create a `bin` directory in your home directory and copy all your script files there (this directory automatically gets added to the path after you exit and re-open your terminal)

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is and old post.
But I just ran into the same issue and unfortunately the solution above didn't work for me. (sorry I'm not very familiar with Linux so excuse the lack of correct terminology)

So if anyone run into the same issue:

1. I ran this in PHP system("/lib/R/bin/Rscript /var/www/html/my_r_file.R 2>&1");
2. I got an error that library sf wasn't installed
   So the issues was that I wasn't the root user when installing the packages.
   S do the following:

sudo -u su -i

Then install all the libraries you need.

I hope this can help someone avoided a day of frustration.